# How to suppress "Program ended with exit code: 0" when running C++ program in Xcode

Tags: xcode, message, exit, suppress

Is there any way to suppress the message "Program ended with exit code: 0" when running a C++ program within the Xcode IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Well in earlier versions, if you try the Target output in the console, it does remove the exit code line. However in newer Xcode versions you are stuck with it if you create a command line project